# Why are Scala XML literals sensitive to whitespace between the tags?

Tags: xml, scala

I've discovered that Scala XML literals are sensitive to whitespace, which is kinda strange, isn't it? since XML parsers don't normally give a damn about spaces between the tags.

This is a bummer because I'd like to set out my XML neatly in my code:

```
<sample>
  <hello />
</sample>
```

but Scala considers this to be a different value to

```
<sample><hello /></sample>
```

Proof is in the pudding:

```
scala> val xml1 = <sample><hello /></sample>
xml1: scala.xml.Elem = <sample><hello></hello></sample>

scala> val xml2 = <sample>
     | <hello />
     | </sample>
xml2: scala.xml.Elem = 
<sample>
<hello></hello>
</sample>

scala> xml1 == <sample><hello /></sample>
res0: Boolean = true

scala> xml1 == xml2
res1: Boolean = false
```

... What gives?

Comment: Because white-space *is* significant in XML -- it is being turned into text nodes. Most normal XML processing (e.g. XPath) just ignores all but select (possible white-space) text in matched nodes though. Hopefully someone can provide a good solution to make it easier to deal with :p

Comment: Demonstration of the above: `<a><b/></a>.child.size` => 1, `<a> <b/> </a>.child.size` => 3. This fact was being hidden by the toString implementation. Why child and not children? I have no idea...

Comment: I had no idea that it was creating text nodes for blank spaces. There's an old Australian colloquialism that expresses my response perfectly: pickle me grandmother!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you liked it you should have put a trim on it:

```
scala> val xml1 = <sample><hello /></sample>
xml1: scala.xml.Elem = <sample><hello></hello></sample>

scala> val xml2 = <sample>
     | <hello />
     | </sample>
xml2: scala.xml.Elem = 
<sample>
<hello></hello>
</sample>

scala> xml1 == xml2
res14: Boolean = false

scala> xml.Utility.trim(xml1) == xml.Utility.trim(xml2)
res15: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the XML literal to a `StringBuilder`:

```
scala> val xml1 = <sample><hello /></sample>
xml1: scala.xml.Elem = <sample><hello></hello></sample>

scala> xml.Utility.toXML(xml1, minimizeTags=true)
res2: StringBuilder = <sample><hello /></sample>
```

Comment: That's interesting and potentially useful. It turns out, though, that <sample><hello /></sample> == <sample><hello></hello></sample> according to Scala, so you don't have to minimize tags first.